# Saving user's data for my application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I was wondering what would be the correct method for saving all user data for an application I am working on. The application is in QT. The user inputs a lot of data into the application and the data will be different for every user. I want the ability for the user to save all the current data to a file that can be user by the loaded by the application again once the user wants to use it again or use it on another computer running the application.

What would be the correct and best way to do this? Do I need to use xml format? And then use the xmlreader for QT? Or do I just need to create my own file format and just use the stream to just read everything in. The data in the file will need to be labeled, because it will need to put the data in certain spots on the gui. And the user has the option to dynamically create boxes and tabs that hold certain information.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

---

A short example:

> I am not only reading gui locations.
>   But the contents of those. For
>   instance. The user is able to create
>   tabs that contain edit text boxes. And
>   those tabs are associated with items
>   that are in a list. When the user
>   clicks on an item in the list the user
>   will be presented with a whole set of
>   new tabs. And each tab has some
>   editing forms. The file will need to
>   contain what is in the list, what tabs
>   the user has created under each item
>   in that list and the contents of each
>   tab associated with the tab of each
>   item in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essense, yes you'll be creating your own file format, but the actual content can just be XML in whatever scheme you need.  Then you can use Qt's built-in XML processing capabilities to pull the heavy lifting of parsing the text (I personally prefer the DOM model, so I use QDomDocument as my base point), and you'll just need to worry about parsing things to and from the individual nodes.

The Qt framework has some great XML samples if I remember correctly that helped me get off the ground almost immediately.  Hope they help!

Comment: Yeah, i was looking at the difference between dom and sax. Which one should i use for this need? DOM seems to read the whole file into memory. And there was a third type qxmlstreamreader, which they suggest to use. Which one should i use if i want to open the file and put everything in their spots on the gui and then only if anything changes, would the user be asked to save the file.

Comment: If you're only reading some GUI location spots, there shouldn't be a problem with loading that XML data into memory.  Like I said, I prefer DOM probably because it's the more traditional programming model.  It's algorithm-like, whereas SAX is an event-like pattern.  That may work great over the web, but for storing settings locally it's not really of any benefit.

Comment: I am not only reading gui locations. But the contents of those. For instance. The user is able to create tabs that contain edit text boxes. And those tabs are associated with items that are in a list. When the user clicks on an item in the list the user will be presented with a whole set of new tabs. And each tab has some editing forms. The file will need to contain what is in the list, what tabs the user has created under each item in that list and the contents of each tab associated with the tab of each item in the list. Will your method still work well for this need?

Comment: Just about any method will work well as long as you've given enough thought to how you're actually organizing the data.  It sounds like you've already got a handle on that.  If your concerned about memory usage though, there's probably a more efficient mechanism than QDomDocument.  I have not measured it so I can't say for certain, but I'd have to wonder if it's memory impact is all that significant in comparison to the GUI.

Comment: Not that concerned about memory. It will be a desktop application. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris: here is the second part of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178946/saving-users-data-for-my-application-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Another great solution is to use internal database implementation (QSQL on top of sqlite). Compared to the xml solution, it might be more versatile (update when needed, can use external keys). Qt has some rgeat examples about using it aas well.

In terms of dependencies, XML solution will require you to use xml and xmlpatterns (if you want to validate stuff), whereas sqlite solution will require QSQL + sqlite plugin. I think that sqlite guarantees atomicity of writing , thus preventing corruption of data (think : the user is killing the app while it's saving).

Comment: I like the SQL solution with SQlite (simple and fast to deploy everywhere), the main drawback is the non-strait-forward parent/child/sibling structure XML provides, but for simple structure it's definitely a good choice. Plus sync/update settings is trivial, no need to keep anything in memory, just fetch data directly in db any time.

Comment: @vrince: can you read my comment below on Chris's post and tell me what you think too? Thanks, the last comment.

Comment: @prolink007 For user changes you will have to track settings change to prompt user for settings saving then update corresponding db rows. I am understanding what your are asking for ?

Comment: here is the second part of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178946/saving-users-data-for-my-application-part-2